# $ \sqrt{a^2+b^2} + \sqrt{b^2+4} \le \sqrt{(a+1)^2+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+1}. $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $a,b \ge 2$. I want to show that the following inequality is true

$$
\sqrt{a^2+b^2} + \sqrt{b^2+4} \le \sqrt{(a+1)^2+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+1}.
$$

I have an intuition that the above inequality is true, but is there any elegant method to prove it without squaring both sides and expanding?

I tried by squaring both sides but lost in the calculation.

Comment: You could use geometry. These are all diagonal distances with the LHS closer to a straight line

Comment: can you explain a bit more? @Eric

Comment: Please avoid math-only titles. These are discouraged for technical reasons - see [Guidelines for good use of MathJax on question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function $$f(x) = \sqrt{(x+1)^2+b^2} -\sqrt{x^2+b^2}$$

We need to prove $f(a)\geq f(1)$ which is true  if $f$ is increasing on $[1,\infty)$.
Calculate $$f'(x) ={x+1\over \sqrt{(x+1)^2+b^2}} - {x\over \sqrt{x^2+b^2}}$$
which can be easly seen that is positive and you are done.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

The path closer to the diagonal is your LHS. It’s not a rigorous proof, but it provides pretty strong intuition.

Comment: This can be made rigorous if you apply the triangle inequality twice or three times :) [+1]