# In proving an inequality involving $2-$norm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

I want to prove the following inequality for $p,q,r,s \in \Bbb{N}$:
$$
\sqrt{(p+q+3)^2 + (r+1)^2}+\sqrt{(r+1)^2+s^2}\ge \sqrt{(q+2)^2+r^2}+\sqrt{(p+2)^2+s^2}
$$ I tried by squaring both sides and simplifying but can't control since the number of terms are increasing. I tried looking at the inequality as a norm inequality of the following coordinates $$
a = (p+q+3,r+1),b=(r+1,s),c=(q+2,r) \text{ and } d = (p+2,s),
$$ i.e. the inequality is equivalent to prove that $$\|a\| + \|b\| \ge \|c\| + \|d\|.$$ One thing I have observed that $a+b = (p+q+r+4,r+s+1)$ and $c+d  = (p+q+4,r+s)$ and hence $$a+b = c+d+(r,1).$$ It will be great if someone can help or give some hints to prove the inequality.

---

Squaring both sides we have to show:
$$\newcommand{\Bold}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}2 \, p q + r^{2} + 2 \, \sqrt{p^{2} + 2 \, p q + q^{2} + r^{2} + 6 \, p + 6 \, q + 2 \, r + 10} \sqrt{r^{2} + s^{2} + 2 \, r + 1} + 2 \, p + 2 \, q + 4 \, r + 3 \ge 2 \, \sqrt{p^{2} + s^{2} + 4 \, p + 4} \sqrt{q^{2} + r^{2} + 4 \, q + 4} $$

Again squaring both sides we have to show:
$$
\newcommand{\Bold}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}12 \, p q r^{2} + 4 \, q^{2} r^{2} + 5 \, r^{4} + 4 \, p^{2} s^{2} + 8 \, p q s^{2} + 8 \, \sqrt{p^{2} + 2 \, p q + q^{2} + r^{2} + 6 \, p + 6 \, q + 2 \, r + 10} \sqrt{r^{2} + s^{2} + 2 \, r + 1} p q - 8 \, p^{2} q - 8 \, p q^{2} + 8 \, p^{2} r + 32 \, p q r + 8 \, q^{2} r + 4 \, \sqrt{p^{2} + 2 \, p q + q^{2} + r^{2} + 6 \, p + 6 \, q + 2 \, r + 10} \sqrt{r^{2} + s^{2} + 2 \, r + 1} r^{2} + 12 \, p r^{2} + 28 \, q r^{2} + 24 \, r^{3} + 24 \, p s^{2} + 8 \, q s^{2} + 8 \, r s^{2} + 8 \, \sqrt{p^{2} + 2 \, p q + q^{2} + r^{2} + 6 \, p + 6 \, q + 2 \, r + 10} \sqrt{r^{2} + s^{2} + 2 \, r + 1} p - 8 \, p^{2} + 8 \, \sqrt{p^{2} + 2 \, p q + q^{2} + r^{2} + 6 \, p + 6 \, q + 2 \, r + 10} \sqrt{r^{2} + s^{2} + 2 \, r + 1} q - 36 \, p q - 8 \, q^{2} + 16 \, \sqrt{p^{2} + 2 \, p q + q^{2} + r^{2} + 6 \, p + 6 \, q + 2 \, r + 10} \sqrt{r^{2} + s^{2} + 2 \, r + 1} r + 64 \, p r + 64 \, q r + 66 \, r^{2} + 24 \, s^{2} + 12 \, \sqrt{p^{2} + 2 \, p q + q^{2} + r^{2} + 6 \, p + 6 \, q + 2 \, r + 10} \sqrt{r^{2} + s^{2} + 2 \, r + 1} - 28 \, p - 28 \, q + 112 \, r - 15 \ge 0.
$$

Comment: where is this from? Do you know if the inequality actually holds?

Comment: $r=-1,s=0,p=0,q=-3$, then LHS is $0$, RHS is $\sqrt{2}+2$.

Comment: Are $p,q,r,s$ supposed to be non-negative reals?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas yes. they are nonnegative

Comment: @CalvinKhor I have tried expanding... the inequality holds

Comment: Sorry, what does that mean? You have a proof that it is correct?

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212846

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I tried defining a function like that...but could not find a suitable one.